# Import backup of external AWS KMS keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, cryptography, amazon-kms

As a disaster recovery measure, is it possible to import an external KMS key to decrypt data encrypted by a previous key?

In the AWS documentation it says the following:

> **Can't decrypt with any other KMS key**
>
> When you encrypt data under a KMS key, the ciphertext is permanently
> associated with the KMS key and its key material. It cannot be
> decrypted with any other KMS key, i̲n̲c̲l̲u̲d̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲a̲ ̲d̲i̲f̲f̲e̲r̲e̲n̲t̲ ̲K̲M̲S̲ ̲k̲e̲y̲ ̲w̲i̲t̲h̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲s̲a̲m̲e̲ ̲k̲e̲y̲ ̲m̲a̲t̲e̲r̲i̲a̲l̲.
> This is a security feature of KMS keys.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys.html

I did some testing where I imported an externally generated key and then re-imported it into KMS (generating a second key with a second ID). Data encrypted by the first key could not be decrypted by the second key (even having the same key material).

But, can any AWS customer back up keys for post-malicious/accidental KMS key deletion recovery?